# Django Reverse Lookups of Foreign Keys is not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

**Info** I am using abstract models in django every thing is working fine instead of queryset i am try to make query for **Domain** which is related to the clients model. But i don't understand why **Reverse Lookups of Foreign Keys** is not working?

**TenantMixin && DomainMixin**

```
class TenantMixin(models.Model):
    schema_name = models.CharField(max_length=63, unique=True, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class DomainMixin(models.Model):
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=253, unique=True, db_index=True)
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(settings.TENANT_MODEL, db_index=True, related_name='domains', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

**Client**

```
class Client(TenantMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Domain(DomainMixin):
    pass
```

**QuerySet**

```
tenant = Client.objects.all()
    for t in tenant:
        for i in t.domain_set.all():
            print(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to `'domains'`, hence you look up the reverse with:

```
tenant = Client.objects.all()
for t in tenant:
    for i in t.domains.all():
        print(i)
```

---

> **Note**: There is no need to specify [**`db_index=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index) for a [**`ForeignKey`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey). As the documentation specifies: *A database index is automatically created on the ForeignKey.*.